# Does Ansible playbook keep on going even if we close the ssh window of VM on which it is running?

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine

My ansible playbook consist several task in it and I am running my ansible playbook on Virtual Machine. I am using ssh method to log in to VM and run the playbook. if my ssh window gets closed during the execution of any task, would my ansible script be still going on and perform the rest of the task in the play ? or will it stop as the ssh window already got closed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have the answer to this since you asked an other question on how to keep it running on such a case. Please do not ask several questions on the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible playbook stops after loosing connection (even for few seconds) with ssh window of VM on which it is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70220721/ansible-playbook-stops-after-loosing-connection-even-for-few-seconds-with-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

The playbook stops running. You need to keep the window open (or use something like screen) if you want it to finish after you close the window.

Comment: it takes around 1 hour for My play book to run, and sometimes even if i loose internet connectivity for few seconds , the ssh terminal lost its connection and thus entire playbook stops. any idea how to make ansible script more redundant to avoid this problem ?

Comment: screen or tmux will help if you close the window, but not if you completely lose connectivity.

You could copy the playbook to the server, then SSH into the server, start a screen or tmux session, then start the playbook from there. It's cumbersome, especially if you have more than one server, but that should work even if you disconnect.