# Ansible playbook stops after loosing connection (even for few seconds) with ssh window of VM on which it is running?

Tags: ssh, ansible, virtual-machine

My ansible playbook consist several task in it and I am running my ansible playbook on Virtual Machine. I am using ssh method to log in to VM and run the playbook. if my ssh window gets closed during the execution of any task (when internet connection is not stable and not reliable), the execution of ansible playbook stops as the ssh window already got closed.

It takes around 1 hour for My play book to run, and sometimes even if I loose internet connectivity for few seconds , the ssh terminal lost its connection and thus entire playbook stops. any idea how to make ansible script more redundant to avoid this problem ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Th is is not specific to ansible. Launching long running command over ssh is always risky if you don't use something immune to loss of connectivity like `nohup` or `gnu screen`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a job on an external system that hangs for a long time and it is relevant that the task completes. It is extremly bad idea to run that job in the foreground.

It is not important that the task is Ansible or the connection is SSH. In every case you would always just "push" the command to the remote host and send it to background with something like "nohup" if available. The problem is of course the tree of processes. Your connection creates a process on the remote system and that creates the job you want to run. Is the connection gets lost, al subprocesses will be killed automatically by the OS.

So - under Windows - maybe use RDP to open a screen that stays available even after connection is lost or use something like Cygwin and nohup via SSH to change the hung up your process from the ssh session.

Or - when you need to run a playbook on that system install for example a AWX container and use that. There are many options based on your requirements, resources and administrative options.